# Retrieve all pdf files store in iPhone memory iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to retrieve all the pdf documents from my iPhone, including all the pdf files that are stored in other apps like Adobe Acrobat.

What I have now is:

```
NSString *path =   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSAllLibrariesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];        
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];

for (NSString *fileName in directoryContent) {
    if ([fileName hasSuffix:@"pdf"]) {
          //add files to an array
    }
}
```

Which only points to one directory.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are only getting the first path to the first directory, so you're only searching that one. Secondly, apple suggests to use the NSFileManager to search. Thirdly, be aware that developers of other apps can save their documents in different places, that you can't access or are not returned by these functions (Just so you are aware of this).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get array of all pdf files in Document directory, then use below code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSArray *arrPdfs = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
```

`arrPdfs` will contain all pdfs in Document directory.